# MS Project Export to XML

Tags: xml, ms-project

I have an MS Project file with separate resource pool.

There are 5 users in the file of resource pool (User1-User5 with unique ID 1-5).

for example, I assigned User2 and User4 to tasks.
[like on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdg4k.png)

When I try to export the MS Project to xml file it returns wrong UIDs for resources. It returns "1" for User2 instead "2" and "2" for User4 instead "4" like UIDs are defined in the resource pool.

```
<Resource>
        <UID>1</UID>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>User2</Name>
        <Type>1</Type>
        ...
</Resource>
<Resource>
        <UID>2</UID>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>User4</Name>
        <Type>1</Type>
        ...
</Resource>
```

Can somebody help me to get correct UIDs in xml export?

Answer (score 0):

I have several options for you here. Others might have a cleaner approach, not sure.

First though, the UIDs of the resources are defined within the .MPP file you are working on. They are not unique globally. The UIDs in the pool file can be different than the projects pulling from it. BTW, I just scanned the available fields and I did not see a resource UID for the pool either.

Here's a work around using this example to force them to be the same.

In your Project.mpp do this:

- Delete resources User2 & User4 with the ProjectRes.mpp closed, just to be sure. You need to get these to go away before any actuals are recorded or this just gets deeper.
- Save it & close it to be sure the changes are commited
- Re-open Project.mpp and let it open the resource pool (ProjectRes.mpp)
- Check to be sure the resources are gone
- Then assign the resources to the tasks in exactly the same order as they appear in the resource pool. Very important. (Do User1 first and make sure it is assigned UID one, if not try the delete again*)

*In the event the resource UIDs get "stuck" you might have to copy & paste the tasks to a new .MPP with a properly pre built resource pool. This can be tricky & requires some trial & error in my experience.

To restate it, the UIDs are assigned sequentially and are unique only to the .mpp you are working in. This is also true using Project Server / PWA / Project Online. The server resource UIDs are not synchronous with the .MPP resource UIDs.

All that said, you might want to rethink using the UID as a key in whatever the target of the XML export is. I've used "inteligent" resource names before, also hard to manage. You are on the way with User1, User2, User3. Maybe Dev001, Mgr004, things like that ...

You could hard code your own global UIDs in a text or number field.

If that's not an option you could also use a macro or formula that pulls the UID from the resource pool file and puts it in a text or number column. I'd have to take some time to sort out the code on that one.

Of course the custom fields will have to be included in the XML export mapping.

Hope that helps. -jw

Comment: BTW - Thanks for the link to the screen shots, very helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification